# How to determine back button press

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am using android navigation components library. I have two fragments set up with navigation graph. I want to do some additional actions on back button press inside of my fragment.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, view!!.findNavController())
           || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

I use this code to handle toolbar up button click, but I also want to handle back button press. How can I do this?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press page. You will find your answer there.

Comment: Is there a way to handle it without fragment manager?

Comment: what additional actions  you mean ?

Comment: I want to notify my viewmodel about leaving fragment to save data

Comment: This is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043428/handling-back-button-in-android-navigation-component

Comment: the on back pressed should be handlet only in the [activity](https://medium.com/@stavro96/how-to-setup-android-navigation-component-with-drawer-88b833312661)

Answer (score 0):

It is another override onBackPessed

[back press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121493/in-kotlin-how-i-can-return-from-fragment-to-mainactivity)

Comment: It won't work in fragment, you need some tricks to handle it.

Comment: added a link to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
            @Override
            public boolean handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Handle the back button event
            }
        });
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);

        // The callback can be enabled or disabled here or in handleOnBackPressed()
    }
    ...
}
```

More explanations in android official guide: [Provide custom back navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back)